# Is there a way to pass argument to the execution of a .bin file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dockerfile

I am new to Linux and I am trying to install a service inside a docker image. It works so far if I bash into the docker container and execute the .bin file manually. However, I am trying to find a way to install it automatically with dockerfile.
Since the .bin file requires me to put in some argument (e.g. yes, no etc) during the installation, I am curious if there is a way to put in those arguments in an automatic way.

Thank you in advance

Comment: First run `./my.bin --help` and see whether it has an unattended installation mode. Many such installers do.

Comment: Unfortunately "./my.bin --help" does only start the installation and does not provide any help XD

Comment: You should check the web site or other docs then. If all that fails, you can see [this cross-site answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338857/automatically-enter-input-in-command-line) for a few different ways to pipe in a set of answers. This is generally a bit fragile, which is why it's always better to try other approaches first